# Show that no such vector exists.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume you have $p+1$ real numbers $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots\beta_p$. Let $i \in \{1\ldots,p\}.$ I want to show that there does not exist a vector $a$ so that

$$\beta_i=a^T\begin{bmatrix}\beta_0+\beta_1 \\\beta_0+\beta_2 \\\vdots\\\beta_0+\beta_p  \end{bmatrix},$$

for all $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_p$.

**attempt:**

One way to show this is to find a counterexample. But I think that when we introduce specific numbers for the $\beta$'s we are able to solve it. We must use that fact that it should hold for all $\beta$'s?

Another way is that it seems likely that if the property should hold we must have that $a_i=1$ and we can work from there, however this is not a stringent proof that $a_i=1$.

Any tips?

Comment: The right part does not depend on $i$ is this the idea?

Comment: @kabenyuk I is fixed, and it should only holf for one i, I could have written a(i).

Comment: What do you mean "for one $i$", when your post states "for all $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_p$"?

Comment: @Joe That the $\beta$'s can vary, they are not fixed, but the equation should only hold for a given $i$.

Comment: And what do you mean by "We must use that fact that it should hold for ***all*** $\beta$'s"? If the $\beta$'s are arbitrary but fixed, then you can find an $a$ satisfying that equation, unless $\forall i>0, \,\beta_i = - \beta_0\ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\beta_0\\ \vdots \\\beta_p
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\beta_0+\beta_1 & \dots & \beta_0+\beta_p \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\beta_0+\beta_1 & \dots & \beta_0+\beta_p \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_1\\ \vdots \\a_p
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
where the matrix is rectangular $(p+1)\times p$ and has rank $1$. This can have solution only if $\beta_0=\beta_1=\dots=\beta_p$. Otherwise you can substract two rows with different values of $\beta_i$ and you immediately get a contradiction. If $\beta_0=\beta_1=\dots=\beta_p$ then it has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, but the equation should only hold for one i.

Comment: I have rewritten it without $i$. Each line is your equation for one $i$.